# Hbase Bulk loading exception (HFile version)

Tags: java, hbase, hdfs, bulk-load

I am loading data into HBase from HDFS.

```
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);

 HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
 HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table);        
 .......    
 LoadIncrementalHFiles loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(config);
 loader.doBulkLoad(new Path(inPath), hTable);
```

Here is the Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid HFile version: 2099722 (expected to be between 2 and 3)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.checkFormatVersion(HFile.java:888)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.FixedFileTrailer.readFromStream(FixedFileTrailer.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:537)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.CorruptHFileException: Problem reading HFile Trailer from file hdfs:...
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:552)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.createReader(HFile.java:595)
```

Can you advice something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try running:

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles
>   pathToHFiles tableName